# Count non-fatal read errors on optical disks

Tags: dvd, blu-ray, cd

Optical disks use Reed-Solomon codes to deal with limited amount of bit flips and hide them from user.

Is there a way under Linux or Windows to count these bit-flips?

Essentially I want to find out how far is my optical archive from fatal read error.

Comment: If you have any doubts over the integrity of your optical storage, it's time to look at additional backup policies.

Comment: I have doubts about everything. It's just the way I am :)